# Hive equivalent to Spark Vector on table creation

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-ml

I have a Spark `DataFrame` with one of the columns as `Vector` type.
When I create a hive table on top of it, I don't know which type it is equivalent to

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mix (
        topicdist ARRAY<DOUBLE>
    )
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path/to/file.parquet'
```

The table creation seems to work and return OK, but when I try

```sql
select topicdist from mix limit 1
```

The error I get:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown hive type info array<double> when searching for field type
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? I suspect you have an extra coma after `topicdist ARRAY<DOUBLE>`

Comment: Sorry, that was just a problem with the MCVE, fixed the question.

Comment: upon querying. Edited with clarification.

Comment: Hive version?...

Answer (score 5):

`Vector` is a Spark user defined type, and it is internally stored as a

```scala
StructType(Seq(
  StructField("type", ShortType, true), 
  StructField("size",IntegerType, true),
  StructField("indices", ArrayType(IntegerType, true), true),
  StructField("values",ArrayType(DoubleType, true), true)
))
```

so you'll need:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mix (
  topicdist struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path/to/file.parquet'
```

Please keep in mind that resulting column won't be interpreted a Spark `Vector`.